# Did not parse stylesheet at 'http://localhost:3000/styles.css' because non CSS MIME types are not allowed in strict mode

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, github, github-pages

After creating my React app locally, I installed GitHub Pages using `npm install gh-pages --save-dev` and added both

```
`"homepage": "https://ryanloh88.github.io/ryanloh/"`
```

and

```
"scripts": {
"predeploy":"npm run build",
"deploy":"gh-pages -d build",...}
```

to my `package.json`. After running `npm run deploy` my website is uploaded to git hub pages successfully and everything works fine there, however when I tested my local app using `npm start`, my `localhost:3000` website becomes un-styled and it seems the styles.css class is missing. When I check the chrome console it says

```
Did not parse stylesheet at 'http://localhost:3000/styles.css' because non CSS MIME types are not allowed in strict mode.
```

Tried finding the issue online but to no avail, help would be much appreciated.

Comment: simple, then take a pull, you may have deleted the style files with mistake.!!

Comment: hi @p4avinash, I re-visited the localhost:3000 console and it has an error saying "Did not parse stylesheet at 'http://localhost:3000/styles.css' because non CSS MIME types are not allowed in strict mode."